# How to get a DOM element in vue 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue2 I have some html in a template like this

```
...
 <td :style="getStyle" v-for="a in d"></td>
...
```

and a method called getStyle

```
getStyle : function() {
    var el = ... ? // how do I get the native TD dom element?
}
```

how do I get the current native TD dom element?

Thanks

Comment: How about using a ref?

Comment: Either use a `ref`, pass it along with the function as an argument using `this` or find a way to not rely on handling the native DOM element directly since that's kinda against the design principles of Vue.

Answer (score 2):

I have the feeling you are doing this the wrong way around. Vue controls the data and renders your DOM. It should not try to get data out of the DOM, as it already has control over all the data.

If you can get the infos you want from the current `a` out of `d`, you can pass it to your function `getStyle`:

```
<td :style="getStyle(a)" v-for="a in d"></td>
```

and the process it in `getStyle`:

```
getStyle : function(a) {
  if (a.x === 'anything') { // the checks you need to perform...
     // calculate the style
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use vue `ref` construct:

```
<td :style="getStyle" ref="myElm" v-for="a in d"></td>


render() {
    console.log(this.$refs.myElm)     
}
```

If `ref` is used with `v-for`, then `myElm` will be an `Array`. Also, it not `$refs` is not reactive.